# How to prove the optimization version problem (whose decision version is NP-complete) can be solved in poly-time iff P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, optimization, np-complete, np-hard

I have proved the decision version of my problem to be $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. And I know that if I can solve the optimization version in poly-time, then I can just compare the obtained minimum (or maximum) with target value in decision version. Thus, the decision version can be solved in poly-time as well. Since, the decision version is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard, so is the optimization version, i.e., the optimization version is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard.

My question is how to prove the converse direction: if the decision version can be solved in poly-time, can the optimization version be solved in poly-time as well?

I in advance thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Consider the decision version of TSP: given a graph and a value k, decide whether the shortest TSP tour has length at most k. One could try a binary search on k.

Comment: But what if the shortest length is not k, how many operations should we call to find the shortest length? Will it be poly-time operations?

Comment: You could start k with a big upper bound: the sum of the weight of all edges, as example. I guess any binary search on that space search should be polynomial. But this is just a guess.

Comment: I think it should be found in poly-time, since we have assumed P=NP, which implies a new upper bound can always be found in poly-time. But, I don't know how to convince myself for such conjecture. I want to show this guess theoretically. Anyway, thanks so much for replying.

Comment: The two words “binary search” are surely convincing enough? Rafael: You get a much smaller bound by just taking a random tour.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/111344/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3278331/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

> If the decision version can be solved in poly-time, can the optimization version be solved in poly-time as well?

This depends on how technically precise you want to be.

The most correct answer is "No". Consider an optimisation problem $OP$ for which the encoded length of the output is superpolynomial in the encoded length of the input. Clearly no algorithm can produce the output in time polynomial in the encoded length of the input, so $OP \not\in \mathcal{P}$. However, the decision version $DP$ takes as input both the input of $OP$ and the guessed answer, so it is allowed time polynomial in the sum of the two, and in particular does not need to execute in time polynomial in the length of the problem per se.

However, if you're guaranteed that the output of $OP$ has (asymtoptically) an encoded length which is polynomial in the encoded length of the input (say $O(n^a)$ for input length $n$ and unknown $a$), then you can do a binary search, starting at any reasonable guess, doubling unless you get high enough, and then searching back down. The number of calls of the decision problem is $O(n^a)$, each call of the decision problem takes time polynomial in $n$, and the product of two polynomials is a polynomial.

Comment: In my problem, my question is given P=NP, I want to show finding the minimum (here is cost) in OP is poly-time. I can find the lower bound for cost. As for the upper bound, it is also exactly an value but have to be found trying exponential times.  So, in such case, can I still find the minimum cost by binary searching in poly-time?

Comment: Did you read the answer? It fails if you have an optimisation problem where the size of the optimal solution is _not_ polynomial in the size of the input. For example “given a set S, find a subset of the powerset of S that is in some way optimal”. If S has a million elements, the solution could be a set with close to 2^1,000,000 elements. But the last paragraph answers your question.